# Windows 7 add printer, cancelled, but port still in use. How to remove?

Tags: network-printer

I tried to add a network printer at www.xxx.yyy.zzz, but halfway it when it asked for a driver, I cancelled it because I do not have the driver at hand.

Later when I try to add again, it tells me the port (www.xxx.yyy.zzz), which is automatically specified as the same as the IP for the printer, is already in use and then suggest www.xxx.yyy.zzz_1

Now, I cannot find the www.xxx.yyy.zzz printer anywhere such that I can remove it and use back the same port. How should I do it?

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: If there is an entry for the printer in your Device Manager, uninstall it. Otherwise, I would think that a reboot would solve it.

Comment: Have you tried simply rebooting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

> cscript prnport.vbs -d -r PortName
>
> cscript prnport.vbs -d -r aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd

Comment: after much searching I finally found the "port" settings page at right click any printer > printer properties > ports. there, I can remove the ports.....